# Как создать многопоточный парсер на selenium?

Tags: python, парсер, многопоточность, selenium, telegram

Хочу написать парсер для тг бота, чтобы парсить ozon и М-видео, используя selenium, т.к информация о товарах загружается динамически. У меня получилось сделать парсер, но работал он поочерёдно, тоесть сначала открывал озон, потом М-видео и выводил результат. А я бы хотел, чтобы страницы парсились паралельно и по мере получения отправлялись в тг бота. Я знаю про Pool, но проблема  в том, что в странице используются разные html классы, и для извлечения инф. о товаре нужны разные функции. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: "о товаре нужны разные функции" так в чем проблема?. есть асинхронный аналог selenium-а - Pyppeteer.

Comment: `для извлечения инф. о товаре нужны разные функции.Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?` - использовать разные функции.

Comment: для параллельной работы с селениумом советую посмотреть в сторону `Selenoid`...ну и банального `Selenium Grid` тоже должно хватить